# Not able to change directory through ftp in php

Tags: php, ftp

I am trying to change the directory with `ftp_chdir` and it shows me the error:

> no such file or directory

But the directory is available at the server side.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
@session_start();
error_reporting(0);
// define some variables
$local_file = $_GET['f'];
$server_file = $_GET['f'];
$ftp_user_name='abcd';
$ftp_user_pass='abcd';
$ftp_server='abcd';
// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

if (ftp_chdir($conn_id, $_SESSION['SITE_IMG_PATH']."x_directory/")) {
echo 'Directory change';

} else { 
echo "Couldn't change directory\n :".ftp_pwd($conn_id);
print_r (error_get_last());
}


 // try to download $server_file and save to $local_file
 if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
echo "success";
} else {
echo "No";
}

 // close the connection
 ftp_close($conn_id);

?>
```

It shows me the error:

> Couldn't change directory

my path is
`/home/website/public_html/upload/x_directory`

Comment: maybe you are chrooted... What kind of ftp server are you running?

Comment: did you check if `$conn_id` and `$login_result` both don't contain FALSE? (meaning connecting was succesful)

Comment: yes they are returning true

Comment: then what does `$_SESSION['SITE_IMG_PATH']` contain

Comment: and why is there a semi-colon in the `ftp_chdir` function

Comment: it contains path of that directory which is `/home/website/public_html/upload/x_directory`

Comment: it was typing mistake improved my code

Comment: "chroot" means "change root". being chrooted means the server act as if the root of the filesystem was the defined directory, so your ftp user is jailed in that directory... Are you running a ftp server on your local machine or on a hosting service ? If it is running on your local server, what is your ftp server pureftpd, proftp,etc ?

Comment: it is in hosting service

Comment: what does return `ftp_pwd($conn_id)` and `ftp_nlist($conn_id,".")` ?